# pandas Groupby sum and concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below

```
+-----------+----------+-----+
| InvoiceNo | ItemCode | Qty |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-001  |     c    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-001  |     b    |  2  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-001  |     a    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     a    |  3  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     b    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     c    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     d    |  4  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     a    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-003  |     e    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-003  |     b    |  2  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
```

I want to calculate each individual `InvoiceNo` wise item combinations. i.e. sum of each `ItemCode`. sorted and concatenated to one string.
Note : in `Inv-002` product `a` has 2 lines.

My desired/required output is as below

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| InvoiceNo |   Desired result   |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Inv-001  |    a-1, b-2, c-1   |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Inv-002  | a-4, b-1, c-1, d-4 |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Inv-003  |      b-2, e-1      |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

so far I have written the below code

```
#load data
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

#groupby and sum
g = df.groupby(['InvoiceNo','ItemCode']).sum()

# Codes to convert the MultiIndex to a regualr dataframe
g = g.unstack(fill_value=0)
g.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
g = g.droplevel(level=0, axis=1).fillna(0)

#calculation
g.dot(g.columns+',').str[:-1]
```

below is the result I get. all the items separated.

```
+---+---------------------+
| 0 |       a,b,b,c       |
+---+---------------------+
| 1 | a,a,a,a,b,c,d,d,d,d |
+---+---------------------+
| 2 |        b,b,e        |
+---+---------------------+
```

please guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`groupby` twice. The first gets the sum for each `['InvoiceNo', 'ItemCode']`. Then we join the code and category together with a '-' and group over the Invoices to create the full string.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['InvoiceNo', 'ItemCode'])['Qty'].sum().reset_index('ItemCode')

df1 = df1['ItemCode'].str.cat(df1['Qty'].astype(str), '-').groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)

#InvoiceNo
#Inv-001         a-1, b-2, c-1
#Inv-002    a-4, b-1, c-1, d-4
#Inv-003              b-2, e-1
#Name: ItemCode, dtype: object
```

---

You will notice I didn't need to sort anything. This is because `groupby` by default sorts the grouping keys, so after the first line the Series is guaranteed to be sorted on `['InvoiceNo', 'ItemCode']`, which is what we want before we `', '.join`

Comment: is there any caveat or compromise in speed, if we do multiple `Groupby` on `dataframe` consist of thousand of rows?

Comment: @Rapto `groupby` is generally very performant and many of the basic aggregations, like `sum`, have very fast implementations, so even if you had 1million groups and 50 million rows it would still only take a second, if that. On the other hand, if you `groupby` + `apply` your own function that becomes a loop over the groups. That's generally a bit slower and scales with the number of groups, but should still be fine. I'm not sure how `str.join` is implemented, it might be on the slower side of things, but with string operations generally things get a little slower

Comment: Great. seems like I'll not face any performance issues. coz' my data consists maximum of 100K rows per file. if I process file by file. things will hopefully be smooth.

Comment: @ALollz I've a similar example. however, my respective counterpart of the `ItemCode` above is number/numeric. when I applied your code, I get an error. any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @Tommy you'll get an error if you try to do string operations on a number. So you would first need to convert that to a string: `df1['ItemCode'] = df1['ItemCode'].astype(str)`, then you can join and do whatever else you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```py
df1 = df.groupby(['InvoiceNo', 'ItemCode'], sort=False).Qty.sum().reset_index()
df1['Desired result'] = df1.ItemCode + '-' + df1.Qty.astype(str)
print(df1.groupby(['InvoiceNo'])['Desired result'].apply(lambda res: ', '.join(sorted(res))).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  InvoiceNo      Desired result
0   Inv-001       a-1, b-2, c-1
1   Inv-002  a-4, b-1, c-1, d-4
2   Inv-003            b-2, e-1
```

Comment: Thank you and upvoted. I accepted @ALollz answer, as it is elegant..